# Android creating a button by tag

Tags: android, button

I am trying to initilize a button with by using the findViewWithTag("TAG") method but i keep getting a null when i try to print out the buttons value. Is there a better way to do this? 
I already have a button variable in my program which refers to a normal Button.

My current code:

```
Button b1 = (Button) button.findViewWithTag("NewTag");
```

Comment: Where are you creating the button? `findViewWithTag()` and `findViewById()` retrieve widgets that you already created elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you've written there, it seems like you might be getting the button wrong. Both findViewById() and findViewByTag() walk down the view hierarchy that you are calling it on, and look for the matching tag or id.

Since you didn't show us how you created button, it's hard to say, but the implication is that you are trying to call findViewWithTag() on an object that you already think is a button - perhaps the one with the tag you are looking for.

Try calling findViewByTag() on a parent level view instead of on the button its self.